# Is there a way to "scrape" the urls of all video and photo posts on facebook using their graph api on a public profile that is not my own?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to "scrape" the urls of all video and photo posts on facebook using their graph api on a public profile that is not my own?
I have been researching for a while now but do not fully understand how to implement the docs on how to do this, this profile is/was mine.

```
#url = "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=myid&sk=videos"
access_token = "mytoken"
import requests
user_id = "myid"

def retrieve_urls(access_token, user_id):
    url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v7.0/{user_id}/posts?fields=attachments&access_token={access_token}"
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json()

    video_urls = []
    photo_urls = []
    
    if 'data' in data:
        for post in data['data']:
            if 'attachments' in post:
                for attachment in post['attachments']['data']:
                    if attachment['type'] == 'video':
                        video_urls.append(attachment['media']['source'])
                    elif attachment['type'] == 'photo':
                        photo_urls.append(attachment['media']['image']['src'])
    else:
        print("notta")
    return photo_urls, video_urls
photo_urls, video_urls = retrieve_urls(access_token, user_id)

print("Photo URLs:", photo_urls)
print("Video URLs:", video_urls)
#myid/target id and mytoken have been replaced that is not the issue.
#I never received the 'data' therefore all my lists were returned empty. I do not understand why. I believe I have all the permissions.
```

Comment: Well it turns out I have to set the app to live mode... So is there anyway to scrap all the post urls from a facebook page without going through their api?

Comment: No allowed ways, no.